# Generating the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing a finite number of sets.

Tags: measure-theory

I want to generate the smallest $\sigma-$algebra which contains the sets $A_{1},A_{2},...,A_{n}$ which are n arbitrary subsets of $\Omega$ . Also I want to try and estimate the number of sets in the $\sigma-$algebra

My thinking:-

Let us call it $\mathcal{A}$.

Then  $\mathcal{A}$ should contain $\phi$ and $\Omega$. these are 2 elements
It should contain each of $A_{i}$ and $A_{i}^{c}$ . So that gives us another $2\cdot \binom{n}{1}=2n$ elements.

Then we have to think about unions of two elements and their complements . Which are of the form $A_{i}\cup A_{j}$ and $(A_{i}\cup A_{j})^{c}$ and also $A_{i}^{c}\cup A_{j}^{c}$ and $(A_{i}^{c}\cup A_{j}^{c})^{c}$ . Which gives me $4\cdot \binom{n}{2}$ sets.

Now I am having trouble as to how to proceed with union of 3 sets. And also after 3 .

Can you please provide me with a method to generate such a sigma algebra such that I can estimate the number of sets ( Many could be double counted , but atleast what we would get is an upper bound).

Edit:- If I mindlessly proceed with the method above . I should get $4\cdot\binom{n}{3}$ elements .

So proceeding this way:-

I should get

$2+2n+4\cdot\binom{n}{2}+4\cdot\binom{n}{3}+...+4\cdot\binom{n}{n-1}+4\cdot\binom{n}{n}$ elements. Is my reasoning at all correct?. Would this be a suitable upper bound?. And would a collection made like this at all be the smallest $\sigma-$algebra ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every element $\omega$ of $\Omega$  can be uniquely determined by a binary tuple of length $n$ that tells use whether $\omega$ belongs or not to each of the $n$ sets.

This determines $2^n$ sets that partition $\Omega$, although some of them may be empty, assume there are $s$ that are not-empty.

The smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains each of the $A_i$ is precisely the sigma-algebra that is formed by the $2^s$ different unions of some of those $s$ subsets.

It is not hard to see that set is a $\sigma$-algebra, since its simply the $\sigma$-algebra induced by that partition.

On the other hand it is not hard to see that each of those $s$ non-empty subsets must be in any $\sigma$-algebra that contains the $A_i$, as each of them is formed by the intersections of $n$ sets, each of which is either $A_i$ or its complement, and since each of those $s$ sets must be in the sigma-algebra we must have that their $2^s$ distinct unions are also in the $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: I get what you are trying to say. I have seen another post on this site which defines a method to generate the sigma algebra. Your answer is perfectly good . I have upvoted . But it does not explain where I might have gone wrong and also why my method was incorrect. I want to clarify my concepts. (I am not yet studying measure theory.....I am just looking into these because I want to study probability theory in this semester and I simply don't have enough time to go through measure first and then do probability.)

Comment: ok, it seems you are missing $A_i \cup A_j^c$ for example.

Comment: Yes those are the type of sets I had a confusion with .

Comment: Well, those mixed terms start to be a trouble, but that whole (some of the terms can be normal and the others complement ) phenomenon is what causes the exponential growth. By the way I think that explosion of options is what makes it hard to just define a measure that extends $\mu( [a,b] ) = b-a$ which is an important part of measure theory courses.

Comment: Can you also tell what do you mean by "partition"? . I am familiar with partions caused by equivalence relations.

Comment: Sure, every element $\omega \in \Omega$ has a tuple, and the different tuple types separate $\Omega$ into different sets that don't intersect, that's what a partition is, one set is the one that consists of the elements that belong to none of the $A_i$, another set is the one that consists of the elements that belong to only $A_1$ but none of the other $A_i$'s, and there are $2^n$ different such sets, and none of them intersect (although some of them may be empty).